# How Do I compare text in 2 files and export to file 3?

Tags: sed, sort, gawk

I have 2 files

1.txt

```
aab
aac
aad
```

2.txt

```
aaa
aab
aac
```

File 3 should contain

```
aab
aac
```

Comment: Duplicate of like at least 3 other questions. Did you search before asking?

Comment: Did you research before coming here to spazz? I've already tried what was mentioned in other questions. And what I asked here is different from what others have posted.

Comment: I did research, and I have the answer to your question, it literally takes five minutes of searching on Google. You wouldn't have had to post this question if you had researched properly.

Comment: `already tried what was mentioned in other questions` please add that to the question... we do not know which question you found and what answers you tried..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `comm` (opposite of `diff`) for this.

```
comm -1 -2 1.txt 2.txt >3.txt
```

`-1` suppresses the first column (lines that are in `1.txt` but not `2.txt`)

`-2` suppresses the second column (lines that are in `2.txt` but not `1.txt`)

this leaves only the third column which will be the common lines

---

In Bash you can use process substitution to sort the files first:

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt) > 3.txt
```

Comment: comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order

Is the error i get.

Comment: You may have to show at least some of your actual input then

Comment: 1.txt

user1@email.com
user2@email.com
user3@email.com
user5@email.com
noname@email.com


2.txt
user1@email.com
user2@email.com

Comment: @patelFrig, so, sort them first.